# How to set outline border for a circular image with css?

Tags: html, css

I have an image with 200 X 200px size, I just set the `border-radius:50%` as below, to display image circular.

```
#circularimg
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}
```

the border is set to `5px` but the picture doesn't display as it should. here is the resulted image.
[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/end2n0qe/ - problem not reproducible.

Comment: I am using Mozilla could be a problem? @CBroe

Comment: No issues I could sense. Can u reproduce in a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below:

```css
.circular img {
  border-radius:100%;
  border:5px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="circular">
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue and the fix?

Comment: add space after circular..... if you are using like <div id="circular"><img src="..."></div> use: #circular img
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}